# emftvm Error during module loading: Metamodel input not found

Tags: emf

I try to launch an ATL/EMFTVM transformation programmatically from a java-app. At the point of module loading (execEnv.loadModule(mr, "moduleName")) an exception occures reporting an error during module loading: Metamodel input not found.

Piece of code:

```
ModuleResolver mr = new DefaultModuleResolver(transformationDir, resourceSet);
TimingData td = new TimingData();
execEnv.loadModule(mr, "moduleName");
td.finishLoading();
env.run(td);
td.finish();
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.m2m.atl.emftvm.util.VMException: Error during module loading: Metamodel input not found
at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.emftvm.impl.ExecEnvImpl.loadModule(ExecEnvImpl.java:1265)
at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.emftvm.impl.ExecEnvImpl.loadModule(ExecEnvImpl.java:1217)
at ATLLauncher.launch(ATLLauncher.java:102)
at ServiceRunner.main(ServiceRunner.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Metamodel input not found
at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.emftvm.impl.ExecEnvImpl.findType(ExecEnvImpl.java:2061)
at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.emftvm.impl.ExecEnvImpl.findEClassifier(ExecEnvImpl.java:2141)
at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.emftvm.impl.ExecEnvImpl.registerFeature(ExecEnvImpl.java:1316)
at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.emftvm.impl.ExecEnvImpl.loadModule(ExecEnvImpl.java:1242)
```

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Did you register your metamodels in your `ExecEnv` instance? You should have a piece of code like this one before the call to `loadModule`:

```
Metamodel inMetamodel = EmftvmFactory.eINSTANCE.createMetamodel();
inMetamodel.setResource(rs.getResource(URI.createURI(inputMetamodelNsURI), true));
env.registerMetaModel(IN_METAMODEL_NAME, inMetamodel);

Metamodel outMetamodel = EmftvmFactory.eINSTANCE.createMetamodel();
outMetamodel.setResource(rs.getResource(URI.createURI(outputMetamodelNsURI), true));
env.registerMetaModel(OUT_METAMODEL_NAME, outMetamodel);
```

In this example `OUT_METAMODEL_NAME` and `IN_METAMODEL_NAME` are the names you provided for your metamodels in the ATL transformation.

[This example](https://github.com/guana/ATLauncher/blob/master/ATLauncher/src/ualberta/edu/guana/tools/atl/ATLLauncher.java) I found on GitHub might also help (credit to @guana)